# Java Swing in Web Page

Tags: javascript, java, swing, web

I'm attempting to create a web page that takes user inputs from form fields and outputs various calculations as values displayed on the same web page. In addition to this, the user inputs create a "Gun" class instance and set its fields. Another class's method within the project generates random x and y coordinates based specific fields from the Gun instance. These coordinates are meant to be used in a Swing class, perhaps fillOval, to draw circles (which represent bullets) over an image embedded in the page. This is essentially a shot simulator.

Can this be done? Can a JFrame be embeded in a web page? Or am I wasting my time? Is there a more efficient language for this than Java?

Comment: can you actually run java on  browsers nowadays? http://www.techrepublic.com/article/java-gets-browser-eviction-notices-from-spartan-and-chrome-42/

Comment: [Java Plugin support deprecated](http://www.gizmodo.com.au/2016/01/rest-in-hell-java-plug-in/) and [Moving to a Plugin-Free Web](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/moving_to_a_plugin_free)

Comment: *"Is there a more efficient language for this than Java?"* It would seem that JavaScript combined with an HTML 5 canvas could achieve the simple requirement (and do it better than an applet ever could). Heed the advice of @MadProgrammer re the fact that embedded Java applets are not viable any longer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can a JFrame be embeded in a web page?

No, at least not directly, but an `Applet` can be embedded.  Since you ask specifically about Swing, you can use a `JApplet`, which is an `Applet` that serves as a top-level Swing container, analogous to a `JFrame`.

As @ElliottFrisch warned, however, applets are a somewhat dated technology.  The biggest problem with them from my perspective is that many browsers do not support them -- either because no JRE is installed on the client machine, or because Java support is not enabled in the browser.  The latter is quite common these days, even on machines with a JRE, partially as a result of a series of unfortunate Java vulnerabilities.

Comment: [Java Plugin support deprecated](http://www.gizmodo.com.au/2016/01/rest-in-hell-java-plug-in/) and [Moving to a Plugin-Free Web](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/moving_to_a_plugin_free)

Answer (score 2):

*Can a JFrame be embeded in a web page?*

The short answer is **yes**, with an [Applet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/). However, applets are an older technology and I would suggest you look into more modern web based approaches.

Comment: Could you offer an example of a modern web based approach that could achieve this?

Comment: [Java Plugin support deprecated](http://www.gizmodo.com.au/2016/01/rest-in-hell-java-plug-in/) and [Moving to a Plugin-Free Web](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/moving_to_a_plugin_free)